# no me actualiza el src de un link que he llenado con un valué de un input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches querida Comunidad, tengo un problema al insertar un valúe de input en un scr de un link con javascript, no se si me hago entender.
adjunto el código y si alguien me puede ayudar a resolverlo le agradecería mucho.

```js
var codInp = document.getElementById("Cinp").value;
var cod = codInp;
var KeyBtn = document.getElementById("Cinp");
KeyBtn.onkeyup = () => {
  document.getElementById('IdPViYou').style.display = "block";
  $("#iFramYout").attr('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + encodeURIComponent(cod) + '');
}
```

```css
.textLinkYout {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.txtLink {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none
}

.ejCodLink {
  background: #3390ff;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="textLinkYout" id="LinkYout">
  <p class="txtLink">www.youtube.com/watch?v=<span class="ejCodLink">SrC5KaIBz4</span></p>
  <input type="text" name="Cinp" id="Cinp" placeholder="código video como muestra el ejemplo..." value="">
</div>
<div class="PreVisVid" style="display: none;" id="IdPViYou">
  <a id="iFramYout" href=""></a>
</div>
```

LO que quiero es cuando escriba en el imput el codigo, se muestre en el otro div una previsualizacion con el link, pero no me funciona.
muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu principal problema es que declaras e inicializas la variable `cod` cuando el `input` aún está vacío, pues la página está apenas cargando.

He movido la declaración de la variable para que se haga dentro del evento `onkeyup`, además algo de limpieza del código y dejar un log de lo que va quedando en el *anchor*:

```js
var KeyBtn = document.getElementById("Cinp");
KeyBtn.onkeyup = () => {
  var cod = document.getElementById("Cinp").value;
  document.getElementById('IdPViYou').style.display = "block";
  $("#iFramYout").attr('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + encodeURIComponent(cod) + '');
  console.log($("#iFramYout")[0]);
}
```

```css
.textLinkYout {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.txtLink {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none
}

.ejCodLink {
  background: #3390ff;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textLinkYout" id="LinkYout">
  <p class="txtLink">www.youtube.com/watch?v=<span class="ejCodLink">SrC5KaIBz4</span></p>
  <input type="text" name="Cinp" id="Cinp" placeholder="código video como muestra el ejemplo..." value="">
</div>
<div class="PreVisVid" style="display: none;" id="IdPViYou">
  <a id="iFramYout" href="">video</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Jachguate Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy nuevo en Programación y tu aporte me ha ayudado mucho, :), de verdad gracias.